# Setting Variables in Module from different program

Tags: python, encryption, module

I am struggling with converting this piece of code into a module in where I can use an outside program to set the variables in this piece of code. How would I go about setting variables in one program and set them in another(to be used as a module) and get the results from said program into the first program.

Here is the code, any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Crypto.Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

SALT_SIZE = 16 
iterations = 64000
salt = 'h5eE0b814M'
password = 'fortytwo'
text = 'What do you mean'
padded_text = ''
ciphertext = ''
key = ''
ciphertext_with_salt = ''


def key_generation(password, salt, iterations):
    global key
    assert iterations > 0
    key = password + salt
    for i in range(iterations):
        key = hashlib.sha256(key).digest()
    print '\nKey: ' + key #Debug Print
    return key

def pad_text(text, SALT_SIZE):
    print '\nUnpadded Text: ' + text #Debug Print
    global padded_text
    extra_bytes = len(text) % SALT_SIZE
    pad_size = SALT_SIZE - extra_bytes
    pad = chr(pad_size) * pad_size
    padded_text = text + pad
    print '\nPadded Text: ' + padded_text #Debug Print
    return padded_text

def encryption(text, password):
    global ciphertext
    global key
    salt1 = Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes(SALT_SIZE)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    padded_plaintext = pad_text(text, SALT_SIZE)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_text)
    ciphertext_with_salt = salt + ciphertext

    #debug script
    print '\nSalt: ' + salt #Debug Print
    print '\nEncrypted Text: ' + ciphertext #Debug Print
    print '\nEncrypted Text with Salt: ' + ciphertext_with_salt #Debug Print
    return ciphertext_with_salt

def decryption(ciphertext, password):
    salt = ciphertext[0:SALT_SIZE]
    ciphertext_sans_salt = ciphertext[SALT_SIZE:]
    key = key_generation(password, salt, iterations)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    padded_plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext_sans_salt)
    print '\nUnencrypted Text: ' + text #Debug Print
    return text


key_generation(password, salt, iterations)
encryption(text, password)
decryption(ciphertext, password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Before your last 3 lines. Then you can import it like any other module and call functions with e.g. yourmodulename.encryption(text, password).